# Is there a term for a group believing their methods are better than another?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing about a rebellion in a kingdom with an unjust government and a cruel monarchy. Like all rebellions, their goal is to overthrow the government and the ruler to bring back order. In the story, another rebellion group in the same kingdom has the same goal. However, they believe that their group is superior as they think they have better methods to overthrow the government. In general, they think they are better than the initial and main rebellion group.

Is there a term for this? If there is, it would make writing my story easier so I really would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group within a group you are talking about sounds like a **faction**. Finding a word for one that thinks they have better ideas is likely to be impossible, since they *all* believe their ideas are better. Since they all believe they are better there was never any need to invent a term for them. Since I write scifi, that has never stopped me from inventing new terminology. How about "narcifaction" (narcissist + faction) or you could take the main idea of whatever your faction believes and put the word "faction" after it. Or you could just call them "the one true way" or something like that, which would be something they call themselves. Or, you could call them the "Those deceived" which everyone else would call them, or use a derogatory term made from their beliefs such as "flatworlder" for those who believe in a flat earth.

Comment: "Faction" correctly describes a sub-group with potentially differing ideas to the whole, but still a part of the overall group or mission.

Comment: You rely on manufacturing a word or coming up with fancy labels, but that doesn't answer the question of "Is there a term for this?". While this is a neat answer, it feels out of place and off-topic for this Stack Exchange. Perhaps you could include a term that actually exists with minimal modification? I think that would help a lot.

Comment: No one would call their own group the "Ideological Supremacists".

Comment: @DenWarren No duh, but the OP made absolutely zero indication he was searching for a term that the group could refer to themselves as. Only that he was searching for a term that exists that meets those qualifications.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is "Ideological Supremacism". Simply put

> ## Supremacism
>
> Supremacism is an ideology which holds that a particular class of people is superior to others, and that it should dominate, control, and subjugate others, or is entitled to do it.

By attaching "Ideological" to it, you're changing the meaning of the root "Supremacism" from talking about people to talking about ideology. This should be the easiest way without having to make up words you'll be forced to define for readers.